# ini_get does not return the original config from php.ini

Tags: php

`I use ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` to get the value of `upload_max_filesize`
but it returns just 10485760.

Even I edit the `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini` and restart Xampp's Apache I do not see a change.

In `php.ini` I have `upload_max_filesize=100M` and even I increased it too 200M.

`ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` just returns same value.

I am using Xampp v3.2.2 on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

1. add `<?php phpinfo() ?>` to phpinfo.php file and locate it to root directory of your web server.
2. type http://localhost on your browser. Check your php.ini file location. Just search on the browser page  as "php.ini" you would see the exact path.
3. If this is not the file you edited, I hope editing this file and restarting your xampp server would solve the problem.
4. But if not and you are sure it is the file you edited, try to stop apache services, from the services list. Edit this file, Then start apache service again.